# Was the monster kid killed by Undyne?

Tags: undertale

Like the title states, I'm unsure whether Undyne killed the monster kid. Is this the case?

Comment: What makes you think that Undyne did such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

No, monster kid was not killed by Undyne.  They were, in fact saved by Undyne from falling off of the bridge on the TRUE Pacifist Route and was told to leave after Undyne had taken an attack that was attempted on monster kid by the player.

Answer (score 0):

No. In the True Pacifist ending, she is shown

> attending Toriel's school